# Threading with python, it works but also give an error output that i dont need

Tags: python, multithreading, count

So there is a problem when I receive any connection on my server, it counts very well but also gives me an error output as you can see below:

This is the code:

```
def worker(count, sequence):
     print chr(27)+"[0;32m" + "  Receive connections IP Address %s" 
     return
threads = list()
for i in range(1):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-51:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: worker() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is all the same for thread 1,2,3,...,51

Answer (score 1):

`worker` expects two arguments but you're only passing one. Add another argument to `args` tuple and it will work:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,[])) # instead of (i,)
```

Comment: Thank you, it solve the error output but does'nt count still in 0 forever.

Comment: @dashboy I'm not sure what you mean about counting 0 in forever. It would help if you would edit the original question and explain the expected behavior and provide sample of expected output?